# search most frequently used word in a selected set of documents

Tags: solr

I need to find the most frequently used words in a given field from a selected set of documents. I tried luke handler,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=my_field&numTerms=1
```

But this query gives results considering whole content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field tokenizes to your definition of the *word*, you can just use faceting for that. That's why faceting fields are usually strings, because the algorithm looks at the tokens generated.

So, in your case, you want the opposite effect.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Faceting gives the count of the docs a word present. I think it can't be used to find the count of the occurrences of a word.
My requirement is to find the most frequent word. There, I can't give a specific word to facet search.